# How can I create XML files from Servlets using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, servlets, jaxb

I just started JAX-B for writing XML files, I am able to create XML files from a java object and saving that file into a local path. I am doing this from a simple main method inside a java class by providing the path.

```
public static void main(String ...s){
    JAXBContext jaxbcntxtobject = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);
    Marshaller marshallerObject = jaxbcntxtobject.createMarshaller();
    marshallerObject.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true);

    Student s1 = new Student(1, "Chanky Mallick","MCA");
    marshallerObject.marshal(s1, new FileOutputStream("e://StudentList.xml"));
}
```

But my main purpose is to do it from servlet or jsp so it can be saved into client machine as download.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

You need to:

1. write to the `ServletOutputStream` in your response rather than your `FileOutputStream` (JAXB will let you specify any subclass of an `OutputStream`)
2. set the returned type to be XML e.g. `response.setContentType("text/xml")`

You should probably set the content disposition such that the browser knows to download the content as a file and present the user with an option to save it under a given name e.g.

```
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "filename=" + filename );
```

Comment: thanks for your help !! i modified my code as you said ..   response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "filename=" + "Employee.xml" );                                                                                     ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); marshallerObject.marshal(e1, out);                                                             But now the xml file is being shown in browser in a proper format , but not getting downloaded ...